# Launching unknown activities from an android application

Tags: android, android-activity, launch

I want to make an android application that shows a listing of applications (downloaded from the android market) and launches the one that the user selects.  From what I've read, I'd have to use intents like this:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setClassName(packageName, className);
  startActivity(intent);
```

I just want to be able to launch the applications, not a specific activity that they could have.

My question is: how could I launch these applications if I don't know their packageName or className? or maybe, how could I get to know their className and packageName, if it's a closed source application that I didn't develop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `PackageManager` to find out the installed applications and such. In fact, you will find [this book sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot/) does a fair bit of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't.  But, Android will let you get a hold of a list of installed packages along with their fully qualified class names.  Check out the code [at this link](http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/70/) for an example of how to get this package listing.  As far as I know, there's no way to determine from where the package was installed, but what you could do is compare it against a list of known applications to be preinstalled on the device and filter those out.  The idea being that if it's not a preinstalled application, it was likely installed through the marketplace.

Comment: Thanks chris, I'll check out the link :)